What counts as a word in a conlang's lexicon?
I'd like to count how many words I have created so far and am wondering what I should consider a word. Is it standard practice to include, for example:

verbs/adjectives etc. derived from nouns (e.g. noun: lbala, verb: lbal, adj: lbalu)
open compound words where there is a single English word equivalent (e.g. darosha tambu - princess)
affixes
proper nouns (I assume words such as days and months would be counted, but what about place names or organisation names?)


Three of the four categories are clearly part of the lexicon, one can be discussed, In detail:

verbs/adjectives etc. derived from nouns (e.g. noun: lbala, verb: lbal, adj: lbalu) Yes Usual dictionaries (both monolingual and bilingual ones) have them separate
open compound words where there is a single English word equivalent (e.g. darosha tambu - princess) Yes, they are for sure lexemes but they are typically not considered words but expressions made of multiple words.
affixes Optional. They are typically seen as part of the grammar and not the lexicon, and they are surely not words. however there are enough dictionaries in the world that have entries for affixes as well.
proper nouns (I assume words such as days and months would be counted, but what about place names or organisation names?) Yes, specially if they are different in form from the usual native or international recognised form. Spanish Estados Unidos is different enough from United States to be an entry in the lexicon. Even if you only add a very predictable affix to place names (e.g. Esperanto Berlino for German Berlin) important place names should be in the dictionary. Of course, Podunk or Kleinkleckersdorf aren't worth mentioning.

Of course, for the stated purpose of the question (How many words ...) only the first category is relevant, the second and the third aren't words at all (but still lexemes to appear in a practical dictionary), and the fourth is excluded for practical reasons (add a big thesaurus of geographical names to inflate your vocabulary? Naw).
